# Can I configure the jQuery UI Tabs widget to go to a new page when the user clicks on a tab?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

The default way of using the jQuery UI Tabs widget is to have each tab's content in a div on the same html page.  Is it possible for each tab to be a link to a different page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you use jQuery tabs instead of normal HTML `<a>` in that scenario?

I guess you could add a tab change hadler that navigates to a new address using `window.location`, like this:

```
$('#myTabs').tabs();
$('#myTabs').bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
    // you can access clicked tab index as ui.index
window.location = "foo.html";
});
```

EDIT, if you want to do this just for styling, you can simply add right classes to your elements:

```
<div class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active">Active tab</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top">Inactive tab</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This will work even if user has disabled all javascript in the browser.

Comment: In this case I would be using the tabs only for the styling and not for the functionality.

Comment: better to simply add right classes to elements, then. I've ammended my answer.

Comment: I think what has confused me is the ability to add styling to jQuery UI widgets either through Javascript or adding CSS classes.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Side Note: For jQuery UI 1.9.1 you need to add 'ui-tabs-active' to the active tab to remove the bottom border of the active tab.